# Efficient way to search data based on multiple attributes

Tags: design, architecture, database, database-design, data-modeling

We are building a system where we accumulate data from many of our internal services, process them and generate set of data called Jobs saved to database. Our client application running on client systems periodically requests for these Jobs and eligible Jobs for the requested client will be sent in the response. For each client request we need to search for qualified Jobs from Jobs table based on client request parameters.

Example:

Jobs:

```
#1
{
    "id": "1",
   "searchFields":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3"
   },
   "job": <SOME COMMAND>
}

#2
{
    "id": "2",
   "searchFields":{
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4",
   },
   "job": <SOME COMMAND>
}

#3
{
    "id": "3",
   "searchFields":{
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6",
   },
   "job": <SOME COMMAND>
}
```

**How search should work?**

We have set of attributes in client request, these attribute's values should match with attribute values in Job's search field "searchField". If client request has attributes "key1", "key2" and "key3" and job's searchField has "key1" and "key2" then this jobs is qualified only if the value of "key1" and "key2" of both client request and Job's searchField matches.

Client Requests:

```
# 1
{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3"
}
Job #1 is qualified. Job #2 is not qualified because request input does not have "key4".


# 2
{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"some_different_value",
      "key3":"value3"
}
No jobs are qualified because value of key2 doesn't match with any job

# 3
{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4"
}

Job #1 and #2 are qualified.


# 3
{
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4",
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6",
}

Job #2 and #3 are qualified. Job #1 is not qualified because "key1" does not exists in input data
```

We have already built prototype for this system using MySQL database, but we feel MySQL is not well suited for these kind of systems. Jobs table is very huge and keeps growing (more than 1,00,000 records added each day) and searching Jobs based on multiple attributes just by using standard SQL queries (without indexed fields) is not efficient. Also, attributes in client request and Job's searchField are dynamic. We don't have fixed set of attributes to work on. New attributes can added or removed anytime, so if we are using SQL queries than handling dynamic attributes would be cumbersome.

**What we have tried?**

We created combinationKey and hashKey of all key-value attributes in searchField for each Job and saved it to database along with job.

How combinationKey and hashkey are generated,

Job:

```
{
    "id": "1",
   "searchFields":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3"
   },   
   "job": <SOME COMMAND>
}
```

combinationKey="key1::key2::key3"
hashKey=sha256Of("key1=value1::key2=value2::key3=value3")

And save Job as,

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "combinationKey": "key1::key2::key3",
    "hashKey":<Hash_Key>,
   "searchFields":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3"
   },   
   "job": <SOME COMMAND>
}
```

When we receive client request, we fetch unique combination keys from Jobs table (full table scan or cache) and generate hash for incoming request attributes,

Unique combination keys from Jobs table: "key1::key2::key3", "key4::key5" ... etc

Client Request:

```
{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4"
}
```

Iterate through all combination keys and generate list of hashKeys for incoming request attributes and once hashKeys are generated, search for Jobs in Jobs table matching these hashKeys.

This approach appears to be working fine in our prototype but I feel it is not efficient enough, because as Jobs data grow, there is a possibility  that unique combinationKey count could grow exponentially and for each client request, calculating hashkey for all combinationKeys would be computation intensive.

**What we need?**

1. Most efficient and easy way to search Jobs table based
   on incoming client request attributes as per our requirements.
2. Consistent and accurate search. We do not want to use
   search engines like Elasticsearch as we need accurate data and not for analytics.
3. Best database suited for these kind of systems.
4. Any companies (such as facebook, google) already using these kind of systems so we can
   analyze their approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You missed several important details: how many results do you expect to get? Do you want to support pagination? If you want to support pagination, in what order do you want the results? How many objects there are in total? How many queries per second should one server be able to handle? Do you want real-time index update support, or is it enough that the index is updated e.g. once per 10 seconds? I may have some efficient data structures for you, but they only work well given certain answers to these questions of mine.

Comment: Table design and queries you are using currently would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements seem to need full text indexing/search abilities which most RDBMs (including MySQL) can do. But if full text searching is the majority of what you will be doing, you might be better off with a noSQL type DB like Solr. Of course you could use both, if you need things that SQL RDBMs does well and noSQL doesn't do well. But from your description of your needs, it sounds like noSQL is the direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, but I do not have db, I have a stream of data which some I hold, some not and data are heterogeneous.

Trick I made is to simplify searching.

"key3":"something"  is transformed into "key3:something"

In such way, it is possible to put many searching criteria into one dictionary and values in the dictionary are HashSets of references of datalines, that has the "key3" equal "something"

Then result is like searching for 3 strings, obtaining 3 HasSets.
Iterating through each HashSet and its references are assigned to Dictionary, each dataline update is incrementing the value.

And result is simply all items from this dictionary that had 3 hits.

I have found it reasonably performing in the task I had to solve...

Answer (score 0):

If speed of retrieval is of upmost importance, you may consider maintaining a separate, indexed data structure for fulfilling searches quickly and without any table scans.

Create two new tables:

**KeyNames** table:

> KeyID - identity - clustered index and primary key
>
> KeyName - string - unique non-clustered indexed

**KeyValues** table:

> KeyID - FK to KeyNames.KeyID
>
> KeyValue - A value for the key
>
> JobID - FK to a record in your Jobs table that has a key with the specified value
>
> The combination of KeyID, KeyValue, and JobID should be unique and indexed as the clustering key. This allows a complete covered index query.

When you need to find a job that matches a key, you'd use something like

```
SELECT j.*
FROM   Jobs      j
WHERE EXISTS 
      (   
          SELECT 0 
          FROM KeyValues v
          JOIN KeyName   n ON n.KeyID = v.KeyID
          WHERE v.JobID   = j.JobID
          AND  n.KeyName  = 'Key1'
          AND  n.KeyValue = 'Value1'
      )
```

If you must search for more than one key, just add to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM   Jobs      j
WHERE EXISTS 
      (   
          SELECT 0 
          FROM KeyValues v
          JOIN KeyName   n ON n.KeyID = v.KeyID
          WHERE v.JobID   = j.JobID
          AND  n.KeyName  = 'Key1'
          AND  n.KeyValue = 'Value1'
      )
AND EXISTS 
      (
          SELECT 0 
          FROM KeyValues v
          JOIN KeyName   n ON n.KeyID = v.KeyID
          WHERE v.JobID   = j.JobID
          AND  n.KeyName  = 'Key2'
          AND  n.KeyValue = 'Value2'
      )
```

This avoids any table scanning of the large `Jobs` table. You'll get two index seeks on `KeyNames` and two covered index seeks on `KeyValues`, then one index seek for each row in `Jobs` to be returned. Also, the indexed tables are very narrow (they don't contain much information) so you'll be able to fix many records on a single index page. The combination of these design features will result in far less I/O than a scan of the wide, unindexed `Jobs` table.

As a bonus, this design allows you to create as many keys as you want, at run-time, without any modification to the data structure. So the attributes are totally dynamic, which was one of your requirements.

The only downside is that it is slightly more difficult to insert and update data, but compared to the hashing approach, it is probably actually easier, and can be done entirely in stored procedures without any CPU-intensive hashing operations.

Answer (score 0):

Place a composite index on key value
Made ID the PK

I think this will work for a relational database

First is eliminate records that don't have all the keys

```
select a.ID
  from ( SELECT table.ID, count(*) as count
           from items 
           left join ( VALUES ('key1'), ('key3') ) searchKeys (key) 
             on table.key = searchKeys.key 
           group by table.ID
       ) a 
  join ( SELECT table.ID, count(*) as count
           from items 
           group by table.ID
       ) b 
    on a.ID = b.ID and a.count = b.count 
  join items as c 
    on c.ID = a.ID 
   and c.key = 'key1'
   and c.value = 'value1'
  join items as d 
    on d.ID = a.ID 
   and d.key = 'key2'
   and d.value = 'value2'
```